# Making a multi-row CSV log using Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to make a CSV log file of a vehicle counting process, here are the lines of code

```
        output_directory = save_dir
        timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d_%M")            
        end_inf = datetime.now()

        count_result = {
            'Start Inference': [end_inf],
            'Finish_Inference': [datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")],
            'Elapsed_Time': [end_inf - start_inf],
            'Up_direction': [up_count],
            'Down_direction': [down_count],
            'Car_total': [car_count],
            'mtrcycle_total': [motor_count],
            'bus_total': [bus_count],
            'truck_total': [truck_count]
             }

        df = pd.DataFrame(count_result)

        file_name = f'Counting_Result_{timestamp}.csv'
        output_file_path = os.path.join(output_directory, file_name)
        df.to_csv(output_file_path, header=True, index=None)
```

The script above will generating multiple CSV files for every minutes. I want to make it in the same CSV file, which is adding new row every minute just like log, not generating new CSV files each minutes, is there any way to do this? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mode="a" which is append and header=not output_file_path.exists() so it doesn't repeat headers every time by using pathlib instead of os.path.join()

```
from pathlib import Path


output_file_path = Path(f"{output_directory}/Counting_Result_{timestamp}.csv")

df.to_csv(path_or_buf=output_file_path, mode="a", index=False, header=not output_file_path.exists())
```

Comment: So it's just add `mode` argument this whole time? Haha Thank you so much! It works perfectly

Comment: YW, please mark as answered